# Why compiling gtest with project instead of using lib

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, googletest

[Google test documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_it_not_recommended_to_install_a_pre-compiled_copy_of_Goog)  explains that gtest must be compiled along with project instead of using standard approach of having lib and headers. They explain that using lib may conflict with "one definition rule". I found this explanation bizarre because this is how you use any other library and they do not conflict with "one definition rule"

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "project", because that is not C++ terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Google Test has a lot of settings that control its behavior, beyond the usual debug/release and 32-bit/64-bit ones. It may, for example, use `tuple` from location specified in the C++11 standard (`<tuple>`), in earlier TR1 (`<tr1/tuple>`), or roll its own, depending on what the platform (i.e., the OS, the compiler, and the standard library) supports. If the portion of the library that is compiled in the binary is configured to use its own `tuple`, but the part you #include into your code tries to use the standard `<tuple>` header, you are in trouble. Google Test is special in a way that it aims for very wide platform compatibility and as such has a large number of these settings, creating ample opportunities for conflicts. In fact, the rule in question was invoked after the developers were swamped by a lot of support calls from people who were making exactly that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

C++ compiler generates binary code which can be different depending on flags, OS bitness; also different compilers could generate different output with same flags (e.g. g++ vs clang++). The standard specifies the outcome behavior, but doesn't specify every details of assembly.

But it's not the worst case. Look for an example:

**SomeHeader.h**:

```
#ifdef MY_W_CHAR_T
#define my_char_t unsigned long
#else
#define my_char_t char
#endif

struct letter 
{ 
my_char_t msg[255];
}
```

Now, you can have multiple "projects" (it may be like VS projects) and in in each you can use **SomeHeader.h**. And let say, all except one defines **MY_W_CHAR_T**. In every project you have definition of **letter**, but in one it's different. Compiler does not add information about struct size to its id. It will probably compile, but the behavior is undefined in most cases. If you will be allocating memory for letter (*letter *pLetter = new letter*) in one project and deallocating in another (which have different definition) you will get heap-corruption error.

It's of course one of possibilities that can happen.

You're mentioning about other libraries. You're probably windows dll/lib for VS? (on linux you compile everything from sources most of the time). Note that they are always shipped for specific instance of toolset. It's because of that reason. Also on Windows it's not so complicated to share binary code like on linux.

Comment: On Linux I do not compile everything from sources. When I build project using standartd c++ library, Qt, whatever I use lib from /usr/lib and header from /usr/include.

Comment: The question remains why other libraries do not pay attention to such things while google test engineers do?

Answer (score 0):

I think Google's document explains well:

> every user needs to compile his tests using the same compiler flags
>   used to compile the installed Google Test libraries; otherwise he may
>   run into undefined behaviors
>   Why? Because C++ has this thing called the One-Definition Rule: if two
>   C++ source files contain different definitions of the same
>   class/function/variable, and you link them together, you violate the
>   rule.

A simple (but not accurate) example:

// Dynamic1.h

```
int GetInt();
```

// Dynamic1.cpp

```
static int i = 1;
int GetInt()
{
  return i;
}
```

// Dynamic2.h

```
int GetInt();
```

// Dynamic2.cpp

```
static int i = 2;
int GetInt()
{
  return i;
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "dynamic1.h"
#include "dynamic2.h"
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  ::printf("GetInt returns %d\n", GetInt());
  return 0;
}
```

What is the expected result of `GetInt()`?
It depends how you compile and link the code, or the link order.

// Compiles so

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared -o libdynamic1.so dynamic1.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared -o libdynamic2.so dynamic2.cpp
```

// Generate main

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -L. -ldynamic1 -ldynamic2
// GetInt returns 1

g++ -o main main.cpp -L. -ldynamic2 -ldynamic1
// GetInt returns 2

g++ -o main main.cpp dynamic1.cpp dynamic2.cpp
// multiple definition of `GetInt()'
```

Note the output of main is different by different link command. And the linker can catch the error if you compile all the files together.

If you just link Gtest as a library, you may get the same unexpected behavior.

Comment: So I understand the issue but why no one else beside google test engineers thinks it is a real issue?

Comment: Moreover I would have some version in google test which is already compiled. Onlything can alter linking of already compiled gtest library are ifdefs in gtest *.h file or linker flags but somehow anyone beside google engineers is not paying attention to such possibility.